# Как присвоить высоту одного элемента к другим элементам на чистом JS?

Tags: javascript, css, css3, flexbox, swiper

Как мне через ***vanilla js*** получить высоту самого высокого элемента слайдера и присвоить его к остальным, чтобы по итогу была одна высота для всех?

На сайте использовался **swiper**-слайдер, при добавлении в него картинок разного размера они распологаются в различной высоте, через [параметры](https://swiperjs.com/swiper-api#parameters) самого слайдера не получилось это пофиксить, **флексами** тоже, задавать жестко высоту через css кажется костылём.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Тут JS не понадобится. Флексами все должно работать. У элемента `swiper-wrapper` должно быть `align-items: stretch;` у элементов `swiper-slide` должно быть свойство `height: auto;`. Тысячу раз так делал, и не нужно городить костыли на JS. Если у слайда есть внутри элемент в качестве обертки для контента, то у него должно быть `height: 100%`.

Comment: Да, вы правы, это я потом нашел, но совсем забыл здесь отписаться

Answer (score 1):

Может кому-то пригодится.

[Тут](https://coderoad.ru/50131078/JavaScript-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%8B-%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-div) я нашел как получить высоту самого длинного элемента.

А дальше уже сам дописал:

```js
function setMaxHeight() {
 
  let els = document.querySelectorAll(".card-img-top"),
    arr = [];
    /* Итерация каждого элемента и добавление их высоты в массив arr*/
  for (let i = 0; i < els.length; i++) {
    arr.push({ height: els[i].clientHeight });
  }
/* Вывод самой длинной высоты элементов */
  let elsMaxHeight = Math.max(...arr.map(o => o.height));
/* Присваивание полученной высоты для всех других элементов */
  for (let i = 0; i < els.length; i++) {
    console.log(els[i].style.height = elsMaxHeight + 'px');
  }
}
setMaxHeight();
```